# Controling NTP drift across my server farm

Tags: ntp

Good morning,

NTP clients were disabled on my server farm awhile back, before I came in. I re-enabled them through puppet and now I get swamped with messages such as

```
Feb 15 06:25:19 *HOSTNAME* xntpd[4153]: [ID 774427 daemon.notice] time reset (step) -3.851946 s
```

Now, I could go the easy way and turn off ntp agents since they're not *that* critical in my infrastructure, but they might become so down the line so I'd rather have a functioning ntp setup, albeit non-optimal.

I'm not that familiar with the ntp protocol; would there be a way to control the tolerance of the time drift, ie control at what point a correction is really needed ?

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: This is a one-time event caused by your predecessor turning off NTP as you're proposing to do. It will keep time correct continuously as long as you leave it on. So the answer is, do you want your successor to curse your name? (And consider that it might be you!)

Comment: It is 2016. Why are you running xnptd?